# File "/i18n/en_US.csv" does not exist

Tags: magento2, error

I tried installing a Magento extension manually but failed miserably, now I receive this error message:

> File "/i18n/en_US.csv" does not exist.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could please provide the Magento version and the development environment (Windows/Linux or MacOS) and the steps to replicate the issue ?

Comment: `/i18n/en_US.csv` file doesn't exists in your extension root directory. repurchase that extension. or contact to that extension developer.

Answer (score 0):

`/i18n/en_US.csv` file doesn't exists in your extension root directory.

Re-purchase that extension.

or

Contact to that extension developer.